# Green LED blinks 4 times, did I brick my Pi?

Tags: raspbian, boot

Out of nowhere my pi stopped booting. The red led lights up, they a long flash of the green led and then a cycle of 4 green blinks. HDMI screen shows nothing. I tried this with two different SD cards, the seconds one is brand new, flashed with vanilla "2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian"

[this page](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) says that 4 blinks mean "start.elf not launched" and that "If start.elf won't launch, it may be corrupt." but the image I'm using seems fine. I've also tried replacing start.elf with the one [from github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/start.elf) with the same result.

Multimeter between tp1 and tp2 shows 4.91V

tried setting `hdmi_safe=1` in `config.txt` but nothing changed.

Have I bricked my pi? what else can I try?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you probably haven't bricked it, but instead shorted it out, which **may** mean that you will need to buy another pi

Comment: @zeldarulez That's very possible... but what could I have shorted out? what do I look for?

Comment: which action of yours on pi brought it to this situation(if you tell we will not do that) i mean like drawing over current from pins or giving more power supply etc..and etc

Comment: Try testing tp1 and tp2 for Ohms. If there is a short it will be 0ohm or very close it it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If so, please create a self-answer (click the "Answer and paste in your solution.) We are working on a project to get the RPi SE up to par and it requires answers to be marked.

Comment: For me, I was using an 256 GB SD, and it was _too large_. Everything worked again on the 32GB and 64GB SD cards I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: go to the store I bought it, get a new board :)

Comment: This is not Apple, this was just a configuration issue.

Comment: Given the other answers available here, it would be really helpful if this was not marked as the accepted answer, as it would improve this question from a search optimization perspective.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to another question:

> [Won't boot after removing and inserting the SD Card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/wont-boot-after-removing-and-inserting-the-sd-card)

That answer suggests that four green flashes indicates that that `loader.bin` failed to launch, rather than `start.elf`.  Have you checked that for corruption?

Comment: Have you read the question asked before posting your answer?

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was caused by my removing of the line `start_x=1` from `/boot/config.txt` file, and in my firmware there is the file /`boot/start_x.elf` and **not** `/boot/start.elf`.

I solved removing the SD card, load it in an adapter and restore with my laptop the line in config.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have bricked your Raspberry Pi, it's very resistive to misbehavior.

I had this same behavior on one of my Raspberry Pi's. Do you use two different SD cards? If you do try an older image (before `2013-09-25`). Also try the newest version.

Are you using a Raspberry Pi made in UK? If you do it might have these problems you describe.vAre you using a Raspberry Pi with a Samsung or NOOBS SD card adapter? If so, it might have these problems you describe.

I think the best way to fix this (without buying new stuff) is to find an image before `2013-09-25`.

You may find [this post interesting](http://www.sysstem.at/2013/11/raspberry-pi-only-red-power-led-is-on-raspberry-pi-does-not-boot/).

Comment: I don't see how using an older image would help, or why a Raspberry Pi made in the UK would be a problem...

Comment: it makes sense, because I actually had extactly this problem, where a RPi from UK did not accept a SD card adapter, but a RPi make in China did. 
An older image is more like a try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your sd card corrupted after doing some type of update to the system. Happened to me when i updated an addon then cancelled it. Just reformat it then reinstall the os.

Answer (score 0):

4 flashes means that loader.bin not launched

Comment: This is what [Chenmunka suggested](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10605/58316) in the top answer; do you have any additional information you could add to differentiate your answer?