# ACT led blinks 4 times

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues, act

My raspberry pi 3 B won't boot. The ACT led blinks 3 times, then it blinks once longer than before, then repeats.
No signal on 7" touch display, no signal at HDMI, config.txt hasn't been messed with.
tried 2 SD cards. one was the original, just cleared and rewritten, the other was a brand-new card with a brand-new image.
All of the voltages are fine.
Already tried following "Boot Problems STICKY" on raspberry pi's forum and "Green led blinks 4 times, did I brick my pi?" on stackexchange.
I didn't find anything helpful, other that they were similar problems to mine.
Summary:
Voltages: fine (3.3 GPIO pin and 5v GPIO pin)
ACT led: 3 short, 1 long, repeat
other forum posts: similar, but NOT helpful
config.txt: not messed with
OS: started blitzing on Raspbian, tried again with Raspbian, then tried Ubuntu.
displays: NO signal
cards: Sandisk (16gb, 32gb extreme)

do I need to buy a new board? I beat my warranty from Vilros by a half year.

**UPDATE:** I have tried NOOBS lite and NOOBS as well
**UPDATE:** RaspberryPi Imager was used to flash sd cards

Comment: I would first try a new download of Raspbian Lite with ssh added to the /boot partition.  Start it up and see if your switch/router find the Pi.  Then try ssh to it.

Comment: nope... :( still same, requests timed out (putty)

Comment: Does it respond to a PING? Have you tried it without anything else (7" screen / keyboard / mouse) plugged in? Can you put it onto a normal monitor and see if anything comes on the screen?

Comment: Yes. only ethernet and pwr connected. No. It will not respond to ping. (I don't even know the IP address. what do you think the IP address would look like if it doesn't get into the OS? I ran arp -a already. as for the IP address in putty, I had a rpi address already.)

Comment: as for the HDMI screen, nothing.

Comment: I would not use NOOBs - just user the standard Raspbian from the downloads section.  I also have much more luck with Balina Etcher on the Mac.

Comment: I've already used rufus. It didn't work either. should try older version?

Comment: and noobs was a while ago, when I wondered if I could start over from the noobs gui. Should I get a new raspberry pi?

Comment: Four flashes used to point to a SD card issue either loader.bin or start.elf not being read / found. If you cannot boot the plain old Raspbian Lite from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ maybe check if the SD card socket looks OK...

Comment: I cant see anything. SD card is completely inserted. Still, nothing... :(

Comment: I just went through the sticky again. I still didn't find anything

Comment: Please have a look at [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151):

Comment: I did, it says in the original question.

Comment: Related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/10579/10937