# Raspberry pi 4 stuck on rainbow screen, green LED flashes 4 times

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, pi4-eeprom

I have install latest(2020-05-27) raspberry pi image 32-bit. And it gets on rainbow screen on both outputs, red lights is on, while green lights flashes 4 times.

When I turn on raspberry pi with out sd-card I get bootloader message.

When I put EEPROM from raspberry pi imager I get green screen that is on for minute then it turns off.

On LAN port orange LED turns on and on my network switch green LED flashes like on other devices, but raspberry pi doesn't show on nmap scan.

I have read and tried all things from:

[PI 4 sometimes doesn't boot after rebooting from command line](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108259/pi-4-sometimes-doesnt-boot-after-rebooting-from-command-line)

[Green LED blinks 4 times, did I brick my Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10579/green-led-blinks-4-times-did-i-brick-my-pi)

[Won't boot after removing and inserting the SD Card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/wont-boot-after-removing-and-inserting-the-sd-card)

And nothing worked I don't know is my raspberry pi dead or is there some error.

I have tried to install both on 64GB sd and 16GB sd.

Power supplay is 3.5A and 5V.

Comment: What resolution is the screen you are connecting to?

Comment: It doesn't make diffrence whetere there is screen connected, resolution is 1280/720, old TV

Comment: Have you read the boot sticky https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: Is it a power supply or a charger?

Comment: 4 flashes - start*.elf not found - how did you put the image on to the sd card?

Comment: `"When I put EEPROM from raspberry pi imager I get green screen that is on for minute then it turns off."` - do you wait until the green LED flashes quickly?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me: pull out the microsd card, wait and insert it again. I can't figure out what the reason is, but it helps. I encounter this problem about 1 out of 10 reboots.

Answer (score 0):

I take that 4 flashes means 4 short blinks and then it indicate a broken SD card holder or a faulty SD card.

Step 1 Try to reformat the SD card

Step 2 Try another SD card

**Potential reason for 4 flashes**

*Note that 4 flashes could be an indication of a more or less broken SD-card connector. If Databit 1 is connected, but one of the other three Databits doesn't make contact, so the SD-card only works in 1-bit (SPI) mode, then this will lead to the four flashes error!*

*Check if all pins of your card holder make good contact with the card!*

Ref.: https://support.pishop.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns